# How to insert social share buttons in drupal 7 using Bootstrap Social Sharing Buttons?

Tags: 7, social-network

I am using module [Bootstrap Social Sharing Buttons](https://www.drupal.org/project/socbutt) in my D7 site.

I can show e-mail, twitter, facebook and google+ but I don´t know how to insert others social buttons like linkedIn.

Comment: Don't forget check one answer as accepted, if you don't know how read this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

This module implements networks by harcoding in the module's code. Because it is not much clean way how to implement modules for this use-case and this module is not widely used, I recommend you to use somethink different.

If you dont't want to include third party scripts to your site (they can spy your users and slows down page) you can use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/service_links It is also widely used, so should be better developed and maintained in the future.

Comment: Thanks Bobik! service_links is very good and solve my problem.

Comment: `they (_helpful_ social sharing scripts) can spy your users and slows down page` +1 for this. I would add "and these scripts are merely a way for the social site to grow *their* tracking mechanism. Once you add the script to your site, your site becomes another node in their tracking network sending *your* visitors' information to them, for *every body all the times*. So your site starts behaving just like a compromised computer/site. This all is cost of an easy way of showing that annoying widget"

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [ShareThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) module ... Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> - Customize your ShareThis code using the STAPI
> - Select node types you wish to display ShareThis module on
> - Choose to display in $teaser view or not
> - Choose to display the ShareThis link in either the $link items, or in the $node->content itself
> - Customize the weight of the ShareThis link if in $node placement
> - Uses the ShareThis jQuery plugin so the ShareThis servers are queried after page rendering
> - Place a ShareThis block anywhere on your site

Comment: Thanks! I tested ShareThis and service_links and prefer to use service_links that generates better accessible code.